# Microsoft.XMLDOM msxml3.dll error '80070005' Access is denied. (The code worked yesterday, I think installing ASP.NET AJAX 1.0 broke it?)

Tags: asp-classic, iis-6

I have some legacy asp classic code that typically runs fine so I haven't replaced it yet (it is on my long to do list though), it runs on a schedule as part of a larger system, parsing XML files.

Today it is throwing an error...

```
msxml3.dll error '80070005'

Access is denied.

/inc/inc_parsexml.asp, line 77
```

Line 77 is:

```
    objXML.Load (Server.MapPath(strFilePath))
```

which is part of this larger snippit:

```
Set objXML = Server.CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM")
            Set objList = Server.CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM")
            objXML.async = False
            objXML.Load (Server.MapPath(strFilePath))
            If objXML.parseError.errorCode <> 0 Then
                'do something here
                session("LogMSG") = "XML parse error: " & objXML.parseError.errorCode & " on file " & strFilePath & "<br>" & Session("ErrMSG")
            End If
            Set objList = objXML.getElementsByTagName("*")
            reDim strNodeParentName(objList.length -1)
            For intCount = 0 To (objList.length -1)     
                strNodeParentName(intNodeParentCount) = objList.item(intCount).nodeName
                If objList.item(intCount).hasChildNodes Then
                        buildNodeNameVar()
                        writeNode()
                    If objList.item(intCount).firstChild.nodeName = "#text" Then
                        If intCount <> (objList.length -1) Then
                            checkParent()
                        End If
                    Else
                        intNodeParentCount = intNodeParentCount +1
                    End If
                Else
                    buildNodeNameVar()
                    writeNode()
                    If intCount <> (objList.length -1) Then
                        checkParent()
                    End If      
                End If
            Next
```

To the best of my knowledge it was running fine yesterday, however I did install ASP.NET AJAX 1.0 ( http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=883 ) on the server (for a different project in asp.net 2.0) so maybe I stepped on some toes?

I hope it is something simple, please help, thanks!

EDIT: Thanks to John, it turned out to be that the IUSER account did not have access to the file it was trying to read...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Access is denied" suggests that your website's IUSR account is denied access to msxml3.dll.  You need to find this file and check permissions.

Assuming that you're not running a really old version of IIS, you should have the current version of the file - msxml6.dll - for which you would use `Server.CreateObject("Msxml2.DomDocument.6.0")` You may find that that the correct permissions are already in place for this version and you aren't denied access

Edit

While I got there in the comments, this answer was wrong.  I should have read the question more carefully.  If the IUSR account really didn't have access to the dll then the script would fall over three lines earlier at Server.CreateObject

Comment: Define "really old." The server is 2003 so I believe that is iis6 (and I tagged the question as such).  The only issue I have with your suggestions is that the code worked yesterday so I don't think (or rather, I hope not) that I need to make code changes.

Comment: The server does have msxml6.dll, so I modified the code as you suggested, still same error. I added the IUSER_[servername] account to the permissions and gave it "full control" (should be overkill) to both version 3 & 6 of the .dll and still same error.

Comment: What's the value of strFilePath?  Perhaps that's the file you're denied access

Comment: wow... you are absolutely correct! (and I don't mean wow as in I didn't think you could do it... but as in "why did that happen!?" The IUSER has access to the folder, but for some reason not the file (that I manually placed, which I have done before) in the folder.

Comment: One thing which has caught me a few times.  If you copy and paste a file the copy inherits the permissions of its new folder, but if you cut and paste then it retains the permissions of its old location.

Comment: I'll keep that in mind, thanks. I've been using "Beyond Compare" to FTP into the server and use it's "move" function so it shouldn't be any different (unless maybe the recent windows patch altered how that works). Thanks again!

Comment: On Windows Server 2019 I found 10 examples of msxml3.dll but the main ones seem to be in Windows/System32/ and Windows/SysWOW64/

Answer (score 1):

I just experienced the same issue. After a lot of searching and trying, it just turned out that I was trying to save a file that was still marked as **"read-only".**

This solved the issue for me.